# Yii2 Check if foreign key exists in migration

Tags: yii2, database-migration

I was creating database migration to add foreign keys. But, before that, I want to ensure that there are foreign key constraints for the given name.

```
$this->addForeignKey('fk-product-user_id', '{{%product}}', 'user_id', '{{%user}}', 'id');
```

How can I check if there is already a foreign key named `fk-product-user_id` exists?

Answer (score 1):

To check the foreign key constraints before adding foreign key. Just fetch the table schemas and check from that.

```
public $tableName = '{{%product}}';

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function safeUp()
{
    $tableSchema = Yii::$app->db->schema->getTableSchema($this->tableName);

    if (!isset($tableSchema->columns['user_id'])) {
        $this->addColumn($this->tableName, 'user_id', $this->integer()->after('id'));
    }

    if (array_key_exists('fk-product-user_id', $tableSchema->foreignKeys) == false) {
        $this->addForeignKey('fk-product-user_id', $this->tableName, 'user_id', User::tableName(), 'id');
    }
}
```